# Finish running a function before proceeding in a loop

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I want the function in my FOR loop to finish running before going on to the next code but I just can't get it to work.

It should fade in fade out the text "Result" before popping the alert window 'Lucky you' but I would see the alert window loop first before seeing the text. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
HTML:
<div id="quotes" style="display: none;">Result</div>

Javascript:
function showNextQuote() {
    $("#quotes").fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
}

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    showNextQuote(); alert("Lucky you");
};
```

Comment: That's not how JavaScript works. You need to use callbacks for this, you can't use a loop.

Comment: `delay` in an asynchronous operation, you can't do that. What you can do is pass a callback to `fadeOut` so it executes when it is done.

Comment: I'm sorry elclanrs, can you write out the code so I can better understand?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/, check the "complete" callback, there are examples.

Answer (score 2):

Since these operations are asynchronous you can't block processing while they're running.  Instead, you pass them a function to execute when they complete (called a callback).  So chaining them like this would look more like a recursive function than a loop.

(Though this isn't really *technically* recursion since the asynchronous operations aren't building up a stack.  It's semantically/logically very similar to tail recursion though, at least in function structure.)

Something like this:

```
function showNextQuote(iteration) {
  // terminating condition
  if (iteration > 4) {
    return;
  }

  // recurse
  $("#quotes").fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000, function () {
    alert("Lucky you");
    showNextQuote(iteration + 1);
  });
}

showNextQuote(1);
```

What this does is define the function, which internally passes a reference to itself as a callback to `fadeOut`.  Each callback increments the `iteration` value by 1.  Then after defining the function it's invoked with an initial iteration value of `1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the alert only comes after the text fades out 4 times. I was wanting it to alert each time it fades. I guess this is what you mean by asynchronous. Thanks though. I'll just try something else.

Comment: @TommyNg: In that case put the alert in the recurse part instead of the terminating condition part.

Comment: @TommyNg: Just in case, I've updated the code in my answer to reflect that.  Note that a browser's `alert` is a blocking operation, so the next fade-in and fade-out is going to wait until you've dismissed the `alert`.  The updated code in my answer will show the `alert` after the fade-out.  If you want to show it before the fade-in just move it above the call to `fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, JavaScript can't do this in a loop, since `fadeIn`, `delay` and `fadeOut` are all asynchronous.

Something like this should work:

```
function showNextQuote(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    $("#quotes").fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
      alert("Lucky you");
      showNextQuote(n - 1);
    });
  }
}
showNextQuote(4);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the alert only comes after the text fades out 4 times. I was wanting it to alert each time it fades. I guess this is what you mean by asynchronous. Thanks though. I'll just try something else.